# How to use cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch elastic search with laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, elasticsearch

I had installed Elastic search as well as  [cviebrock / laravel-elasticsearch](https://github.com/cviebrock/laravel-elasticsearch/tree/2.0)
library for my laravel project.
Now my question is how can i use this library to search from database records.I have figured couple of references but found nothing on my point.
with laravel i have to implement simply search functionality with the help of elastic search.
I have just installed all the dependencies. not done any code trying to find how to start.
How can i index all the records of database automatically and at the search how can i get result using elastic search.

Please help.any help will appreciated.

Comment: Why are you down voting this? Have seen any totorial that describe step by step that how to use it?
If you dont know about it than why down voting and if know that this question is scrap than answer the question.

Comment: can anyone help me out of this?

Comment: In this package, you need to use the curl calling of Elastic search API during insert, update, delete and get the data from Elastic search DB. I have a similar type of problem with this package. There is some error inside a package to initialize elastic search with the package's method.
For accurate functionality, I think you need to use this working package instead of cviebrock / laravel-elasticsearch.

Working package LINK : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/current/index.html